# Self hosted GRPC server

Tags: c#, grpc, grpc-dotnet

I am attempting to transition away from WCF to move our codebase across to .NET Core.  Our services are all hosted as Windows services at present so am trying to self-host the gRPC service as well (rather than building `AspNetCore` applications).  I have successfully built a server using `Grpc.Core.Server`, and the client side as well with `Grpc.Net.Client.GrpcChannel`, see the code snippets below for reference.

Server:

```
  var builder = ServerServiceDefinition.CreateBuilder();
  // Binder is a small class ripped from the CodeFirst example
  var binder = new Binder();
  binder.Bind(builder, serviceType, service: serv);
  var serverServiceDefinition = builder.Build();

  var server = new Grpc.Core.Server
  {       
    Services = { serverServiceDefinition },
    Ports = { new ServerPort(host, port, ServerCredentials.Insecure) }
  };

  server.Start();
```

Client:

```
  var channel = GrpcChannel.ForAddress(Uri, new GrpcChannelOptions()
  {
    //HttpHandler = new GrpcWebHandler(new System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler())
  });
  var service = channel.CreateGrpcService<TService>();
```

However because our applications are still running in `.Net Framework 4.8` I get the runtime exception when testing out this code:

> System.PlatformNotSupportedException : gRPC requires extra configuration on .NET implementations that don't support gRPC over HTTP/2. An HTTP provider must be specified using GrpcChannelOptions.HttpHandler.The configured HTTP provider must either support HTTP/2 or be configured to use gRPC-Web. See https://aka.ms/aspnet/grpc/netstandard for details.

That leads me to add in the `Grpc.Net.Client.Web.GrpcWebHandler` on the client side to switch over to `Grpc-web` as per the link in the error.

However, I am now struggling to do the equivalent for the server to support `Grpc-web`.  The guide [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/grpc/browser?view=aspnetcore-5.0#configure-grpc-web-with-the-net-grpc-client) suggests to either (1) use `Grpc.AspNetCore.Web` or (2) use "Envoy proxy" to get the server supporting it.  The problem with (1) is that I'm not using `AspNetCore` so I don't think this solution is appropriate, and I can't find any lightweight/easy way to do (2) in a simple C# solution.

Without the server-side support added, I get this exception:

> Grpc.Core.RpcException : Status(StatusCode="Internal", Detail="Error starting gRPC call. HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request. WebException: The server committed a protocol violation. Section=ResponseStatusLine", DebugException="System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request.

Which I assume is obviously related to the fact the server isn't supporting the `Grpc-web` requests.  So I am at a bit of a dead end with regards to this now.  I feel I need to work out how to self-host `AspNetCore` servers and move to that instead of `Grpc.Core.Server`, which will open up option (1), but I am finding little to no evidence that is actually possible.

So I guess my main question is: Is there any way to support `Grpc-web` clients in a server hosted via `Grpc.Core.Server`?

And if the answer is **no** --> How can I self-host a GRPC server that will support `Grpc-web` clients?

Comment: May I ask, why aren't you using https://github.com/grpc/grpc-dotnet instead of https://github.com/grpc/grpc ?

Comment: @RandRandom I wanted a code-first solution which led me to protobuf-net.Grpc, which is what I've based my solution off.  We have an existing WCF code base using [DataContract] and [ServiceContract] interfaces/classes, so we are not interested in .proto files.  I also want to self-host C# server & clients.  It seems I'm limited in what is available that ticks these boxes?

Answer (score 0):

As per [this getting started guide](https://protobuf-net.github.io/protobuf-net.Grpc/gettingstarted#:%7E:text=Did%20you%20mention%20that%20it%20works%20on%20.NET%20Framework%20too%3F) I have discovered `protobuf-net.Grpc.Native` which appears to solve the problem I have at the moment.  I also discovered I was missing a default constructor for my `[DataContract]`, which I think was unrelated to the errors I was receiving but may have been contributing.